# Proportion of variance explained, prediction accuracy, and noisy criterion variables

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, roc, signal-detection

> A given criterion measure is corrupted by noise such that only 60% of its variance is attributable to a true signal. This noisy measure of outcome is regressed against some number of predictors and a linear model is produced. What percentage of the true signal variance must be accounted for by the predictors such that an estimated criterion score observed to be 3 SD from the mean can be identified as such with 80% accuracy? What about for 2 SD? 1 SD? What is the relationship between signal corruption, desired accuracy of prediction, proportion of variance explained, and extremity of the predicted score from the mean? Assume the criterion variable is normally distributed with unit variance and zero mean. Assume that the noise is uncorrelated with the true signal.

I'm able to intuit that (A) corruption of the signal imposes limitations on prediction accuracy, even when 100% of variance in the true signal is accounted for by the predictors. I also realize that in order to achieve comparable accuracy, (B) a model need account for less variance in predicting more extreme, estimated criterion scores compared to those falling closer to the mean.

I'm struggling to make sense of these relationships quantitatively and welcome any relevant theory pertaining to this problem.